# From local to global diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold. Let $B \cong S^1$ be its boundary. Assume there exists a diffeomorphism $\phi$ from some neighbourhood $U \subset M$ of $B$ to $S^1 \times [0,1)$.

$M$ can be embedded in four-dimensional space. Does there exist a diffeomorphism from $M$ to $f(M) \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ so that $f(U) = \{ (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta), z,0) |\theta \in [0, 2 \pi], z \in [0,1) \}$?

I am intuitively completely convinced that such a diffeomorphism must exist, but practically rather stumped how to actually construct it using $\phi$. I.e. I don't know if $\phi$ can be 'extended' to include all of $M$ while retaining its original image on $U$.

Comment: Just to clarify, is $S^1$ the circle in this problem?

Comment: @SamSkywalker, yes, it is the circle. I took this as an example, but the main property I need is for the boundary to be compact.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed true since your $M$ is a surface. A proof requires some work though. One way to argue is to go through the step of the proof of Whitney embedding theorem (say, every surface embeds in $R^4$). Another is to argue that all 1-dimensional smooth framed knots in $R^4$ are smoothly ambiently isotopic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be false, if I am not wrong. Regard the Möbius strip as a real projective plane with an open disc removed. This surface has $S^1$ as border and there is a diffeomorphism $\phi$ as the one you request.

However, the Möbius strip cannot be embedded into $\mathbb R^3$ as a cylinder because the former is non-orientable while the later is orientable. So there cannot be a diffeomorphism like the $f$ in the question.

However, I think we would have quite a different answer if we had more flexibility in the $z$ component of $f$. Were this the case, I am at this moment inclined to believe that *all* manifolds with $S^1$ as border can be embedded into $\mathbb R^3$, but at this moment I can think of no proof of this statement.

Apologies in advance if I turn out to be wrong.

Comment: The question as asked does not require the Möbius strip to be embedded as a cylinder, only that a neighborhood of its boundary circle to be embedded as a cylinder.

Comment: Right, I mixed it up.

What if we remove an open disc from the Möbius strip and we glue it with the $U$ from the problem?

Comment: The manifold can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by assumption. I had to choose a number to be able to properly define the parametrisation; however, as far as I'm concerned, manifolds  embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4} are fine too. I edited my original question to generalise.

Comment: Well, that assumption wasn't in the question (I suggest you edit it to show it).

Still, I need to think about it.